# how to parse a matematical expression in C

Tags: c, function, parsing, math

In my program I need to handle mathematical expressions like:

```
sin(x) + x^2 + x
```

so I have to create a C function like:

```
double my_function(double x) {
  return sin(x) + x*x + x;
}
```

The problem is that the program has to manage any kind of function whose form factor is not known a priori.

The function has to be read from a .txt file, is there any method to parse them?

Comment: No, standard C does not specify such a function.

Comment: Have you looked at parser generator tools such as bison/Yacc + flex/Lex?  Usually one of the first examples given is a calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many available projects doing it.

For example: https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr

Clone, test & see how it is done